# removal of elements from a loaded iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website with an iFrame element inside it.  Now I need to remove a particular element from the website that is being loaded in the iFrame.

I am using javascript.  The link mentioned is in the same server.  I loaded the jquery in the head of the site.

```
<iframe id="ContentiFrame" src="LINK" class="section main"  width="998" height="200" frameBorder="0"> 
</iframe>

<script>
$(this).load("LINK")
$(window).on('load', function() 
{
            var $iframe = $('#ContentiFrame'); //this is the name of the iframe ... EDITED added #before name
              var $contents = $iframe.contents();
              var $logo = $contents.find('.logoContainer');
              $logo.remove(); 
}); 
</script>
```

For some reason, this is not working for me.   Thanks for any help.

Comment: var $iframe = $('#ContentiFrame');

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `#` on the ID of the `iFrame`.
Try this:

```
var $iframe = $('#ContentiFrame'); 
                 ^
```

Comment: ok .. edited in the question .. that's good to start with, but it is still not working.

Comment: @user2151973, do you get any console errors? Is ('.logoContainer') available by time of parent window dom ready?

Comment: The script code is before the </body> tag.  I also encapsulated the code after the .load in a  '$(document).ready(function() {... } ;' so i don't think its because it is not ready.

Comment: I am a bit new to this technology tbh .. where do i need to check please? .. the apache tomcat console?

Comment: @user2151973, I mean your browser console. Which browser do you use? Otherwise you can share a live link to the problem.

Comment: i'm using firefox.  The website is not yet live so I can't really give links.  However I'm going to solve this by changing the actual html itself since it's far easier, since the other website is ours.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `#` for id

`var $iframe = $('#ContentiFrame');`

Comment: ok .. edited in the question .. that's good to start with, but it is still not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery scope parameter：

```
var iframe = $('#ContentiFrame'); 
var iframebody=$iframe.get(0);
var body=iframebody.contentWindow.document.body;
var logo=$("#ContentiFrame",body);
logo.remove();
```

I sugget include a jquery.js in iframe page,so you can do like this:

```
var iframe = $('#ContentiFrame'); 
var iframebody=$iframe.get(0);
var frameWindow=iframebody.contentWindow;
var logo=frameWindow.$("#ContentiFrame");
logo.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("ContentiFrame").contentDocument.querySelectorAll('.logoContainer').remove();
```